# Using C++ templates to create a class with custom components

Tags: c++, templates

Let me explain what I am asking for by an example. Imagine I have a class for a car.
Now, the car may have a lot of extras:

- 4 doors instead of only 2
- Automatic door locking
- 4 Wheel drive

I want to create the class with any combination of these options. Any of these options needs some data members. Imagine the class now looks like this:

```
class Car {
public:
  bool FourDoors;
  bool AutomaticDoorLocking;
  bool FourWheelDrive;

  Door doors[4];  //4 only needed if FourDoors=true
  DoorLockingElectronic doorElectronic; //Only needed if AutomaticDoorLocking=true
  TransmissionsShafts[4]; //4 only needed for FourWheelDrive=true

  void lockDoors() {
    if (AutomaticDoorLocking) {
      doorElectronic.lockDoors();
    } else {
      // Do manual door locking
    }
  }
};
```

So far so good, but now I want to create a lot of cars, so many that memory gets critical. And I do not need most of the extras in most of those cars.
I could create a base class, and derive classes with those options enabled or disabled.
But I would have to create 2^{#extras} classes to create all possible combinations, with a lot of double code.

So I thought maybe templates could be used? (that is the question).

I can imagine having a flag template, and rewrite the lockDoors like this:

```
template<int flags>
void Car<flags>::lockDoors() {
  if (flags | AutomicDoorLockingFlag) {
    doorElectronic.lockDoors();
  } else {
    // Do manual door locking
  }
}
```

Wonderful! But the class Car<0> still takes a lot of unnecessary space. So:

Can I somehow include or exclude class members depending on a template parameter?

Other Ideas how to deal with the situation are also welcome!

Comment: You're not "saving memory" by reducing the amount of typing required to instantiate a class. Three classes and three instances of a templated class require exactly the same amount of memory.

Comment: That is exactly what I am asking, can I by using a template argument exclude a data member of class and thereby reduce the memory needed for an instance of that class with that template argument.

Comment: Why don't you simply inherit from a base 'Car' class ?

Comment: beware also that if you do that, then your different objects of different sizes and different types can no longer be elements of the same container. This may be very bad news indeed when you come to create "a lot of" them.

Comment: @meagar: You minimize memory footprint, but not code. If you have 3 different features, with 3 different options each then you have 27 different classes to write. This is inefficient.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to use policy classes:

```
class FourDoorPolicy { Door m_doors[4]; ... };
class TwoDoorPolicy { Door m_doors[2]; ... };

class AutoDoorLockingPolicy { ... };
class ManualDoorLockingPolicy { void lockDoors(); ... };

class FourWheelDrivePolicy { TransmissionShafts m_shafts[4]; ... };
class TwoWheelDrivePolicy { TransmissionShafts m_shafts[2]; ... };

template <class DoorPolicy = TwoDoorPolicy,
          class LockingPolicy = ManualDoorLockingPolicy,
          class DrivePolicy = TwoWheelDrivePolicy>
class Car : public DoorPolicy, public LockingPolicy, public DrivePolicy
{
  ...
};
```

Put all the policy specific stuff (e.g. `lockDoors()` function) inside the policy classes rather than the `Car` class. The `Car` class inherits these, which is a form of composition (i.e. you are building all their functionality into the `Car` class).

Note that you should give all the policy classes a `protected`, non-`virtual` destructor so that they can only be instantiated as part of a derived class.

You then instantiate customised cars in the normal template manner:

```
Car<FourDoorPolicy, AutoDoorLockingPolicy, TwoWheelDrivePolicy> myCar;
```

Of course, you can use `typedef`s to help with this (and template aliases in C++0x will help a lot, too).

See: [Policy-based Design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Policy-based_design)

Comment: Not a criticism as I am reading up on policy-based design as we speak, but how does this come across when you want to read a car and its features from disk, or arbitrarily build a car with any kind of feature?

Comment: That's fine, but you'll need to add an extra level of indirection to cope with the dynamic varying object structures (i.e. create an `ICar` that they all derive from). Reading the car from disk would involve constructing a specific specialised Car<X, Y, Z> and returning it as an `ICar`. In that case you'd probably also want to provide some virtual functions for a dynamic interface, but that is easy as well.

Comment: Unless I misunderstand you (entirely possible!), would this not mean an incredible number of specialized Car<X, Y, Z>s, given the amount of permutations?  Using the OP's original source material, cars come with a retarded amount of option packs (manufacturer AND dealer), and this spreads across every make, model and series/derivative.  Are you saying you need a specific Car<X, Y, Z> for each permutation?  Once again, I may have missed something :)

Comment: @Moo: Templates get fixed at compile-time, so if you want behavior depending on run-time parameters, templates are clumsy.

Comment: @Moo: Yes, having lots of combinations of lots of features code result in a lot of code bloat (note that good compilers might be able to fold many of the functions together). Some parameters might be better as constructor parameters (e.g. the manufacturer). The template policies are best for things that affect structure, or where raw specialisation is required.

Comment: @sbi, and I think that is my problem with using policies as a solution to this.  The combinations of make, model and series is enormous and the amount of features available in each just exasperates the problem.  I do not believe policies are a good solution in this case.

Comment: @Moo: What is your proposal? I appreciate your criticism, but criticism without suggesting an alternative isn't very good criticism (reminds me of Churchill - "Indeed, it has been said that democracy is the worst form of government except all those other forms that have been tried from time to time.")

Comment: @Peter, I suggested an alternative that described features as components that could then be added to a car in a vector.  Whilst this does incur a memory overhead, it does allow one to define vehicle-feature-packs, and represent any combination of car/features in a simple way.  That said, the OP has not described what he is doing with this car and it may well turn out that polices are a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

You probably should look into [Policy-based design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Policy-based_design). Basically, it consists as externalizing behaviors in policy classes and instantiating a template car object with the appropriate policies. A policy class is responsible for the encapsulation of a given behavior.

From an implementation point of view : `Car` becomes a template where each type argument corresponds to a given policy (for example : `DoorLockingPolicy`). Your car template can then be "configured" depending the types you choose to instantiate it with : `ManualDoorLockingPolicy` or `AutomaticDoorLockingPolicy`.

```
template<class DoorLockingPolicy /*, class DoorsPolicy, ... */>
class Car : DoorLockingPolicy
{
public:
 void lockDoors()
 {
  /* ... */
  DoorLockingPolicy::lockDoors();
 }
};

struct ManualDoorLockingPolicy
{
 void lockDoors() { /* ... */ }
};

struct AutomaticDoorLockingPolicy
{
 void lockDoors() { /* ... */ }
};

int main()
{
 Car<ManualDoorLockingPolicy> car1;
 Car<AutomaticDoorLockingPolicy> car2;
}
```

From a performance point of view, policy-based design is a great way to achieve "don't pay for what you don't use" :

- Calls to the policy classes can be inlined and introduce no additional cost
- The `Car` template can inherit privately from its policies and benefit from the empty base optimization.

Once again, Modern C++ Design (Andrei Alexandrescu) is a great read on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be to introduce a feature class.  The feature class would have some kind of a unique identifier (I've used `int` for the hell of it, but `boost::uuids::uuid` would be more preferable).  It does nothing but define a feature of some sort:

```
class Feature
{
private:
    int m_nUniqueID;

protected:
    Feature(int _uniqueID) : m_nUniqueID(_uniqueID) {};
    virtual ~Feature(){};

public:
    const int& getUniqueID const {return(m_nUniqueID);};

}; // eo class Feature
```

From this, we can derive more concrete features:

```
class DoorsFeature : public Feature
{
private:
    int m_nDoors;

public:
    static const int UniqueId;
    DoorsFeature(int numDoors) : Feature(UniqueId), m_nDoors(numDoors){};
    virtual ~DoorsFeature(){};

    void lockDoors() { /* lock the doors */ };
}; // eo class DoorsFeature

class ABSFeature : public Feature
{
public:
    static const int UniqueId;
    ABSFeature() : Feature(UniqueId){};
    virtual ~ABSFeature(){};
}; // eo class ABSFeature
```

And onwards for any kind of feature that the car can have.  Note I would not class *wheels* as a feature because, well, all cars have wheels although the number may differ.  I am referring to various traits that can differ wildly such as electronic doors, ABS, etceteras.  Suddenly, your car becomes a much simpler container:

```
class Car
{
private:
    int m_nWheels;
    std::string m_Colour;
    std::vector<Feature> m_Features;

protected:

public:
    Car();
    ~Car();

    void addFeature(Feature& _feature) {m_Features.push_back(_feature);};
    Feature getFeature(int _featureId) const;

    void lockDoors()
    {
        DoorsFeature& doorsFeature(static_cast<DoorsFeature&>(getFeature(DoorsFeature::UniqueId)));
        doorsFeature.lockDoors();
    } // eo lockDoors
}; // eo class Car
```

Given this, you can also go a step further and introduced named feature-sets (much like the option packs you get from a dealer/manufacturer) that can be automatically applied to a car, or range of makes, models and series.

Obviously, I've left a lot out.  You may want to pass a reference to the car to each feature, or do otherwise.

Comment: This looks promising, but I am not sure I fully get it. How would you write the lockDoors function here?

Comment: Find the feature by the unique ID and call a function.  I've modified the code to show this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem as I see it is that you're trying to define a single class which is capable of representing all possible version of a "Car", meaning that each instance contains member data capable of representing all possible cars. This problem was solved eons ago by traditional inheritance.

Define the functionality common to all cars in the base class. Then derive specific classes which add functionality (and member variables which increase the memory footprint). You minimize your memory simply by instantiating the proper sub class. Each instance contains only the members important to that specific type of Car.

Comment: Yes, but to get all possible combination of extras, I would need 2^(#extras) classes, which can be a lot.

Comment: That's only a problem from an OO POV. C++, however, is a multi-paradigm language and shines brightest where you mix paradigms (like putting base class smart pointers to derived classes into STL containers). OO is not the only way to structure the world. Follow the links in some other answers to policy-based design. That might be an eye-opener.

Answer (score -1):

Try rewriting your code to use `vector` instead of arrays.  You can use just the space you need, and it's easier too.

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
class Car
{
public:
  int getDoorCount() { return doors.size(); }
  bool isFourWheelDrive() { return transmissionShafts.size() == 4; }
  bool areDoorsAutoLocking() { return automaticDoorLocking.get() != NULL; }
  void lockDoors() {
    if (automaticDoorLocking.get() != NULL) {
      automaticDoorLocking->lockDoors();
    } else {
      // Do manual door locking
    }
  }

private:
  std::vector<Door> doors;
  std::vector<TransmissionsShafts> transmissionShafts;
  std::auto_ptr<DoorLockingElectronic> automaticDoorLocking;

};
```

Notice how `Car` now supports hatchbacks (5 doors).

Comment: This is most certainly not more memory efficient than the code the OP posted, and memory efficiency is the issue here.

Comment: @Space: How so?  3-bytes fewer for the unnecessary bools, 3x fewer TransmissionsShafts for most cars, and Storing a pointer to the DoorLockingElectronic instead of the entire class make up for the extra memory vector needs.